# Size Classes causing bother in universal app

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift

Xcode 6 Beta3, Swift:

I am generating many subviews programmatically, whose sizes and positions are dependent on the size of their (shared) superview.

I am trying to use the new size classes, but I find that the superview bounds are not behaving as I had expected, I suspect a conflict between what the autoresizing is doing and the point at which I use the superview's bounds to set the subviews' dimensions (at which point the superview's dimensions seem to resemble those of the IB wAny hAny setting), but it seems to follow no pattern that I can master.

This is a new project created in XC6b3.

All very unspecific, I know, but any advice on getting subviews back under control would be much appreciated.

Comment: Can you use Auto Layout?